# How to integrate a switch statement in Swift UI? Where should it go in the document?

Tags: swift, swiftui, switch-statement

I get an error with the following on the line where my switch statement starts. I am completely new to Swift UI and lost at times on where some logic should go. In short I have two pickers and I want to make a switch statement to help choose what formula should be used to convert the temperature. I keep getting errors though wherever I put the switch statement. I essentially wanted to switch on two potential values and then choose the formula.

First: Where should my logic go for the switch?
Second: This might be a horrible way to go about this, any way to be more organized with my app?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var inputTemp: Double = 0
    @State private var inputUnit: String = "Celcius"
    @State private var outputTemp: Double  = 0
    @State private var outputUnit: String = "Fahrenheit"
    
    let tempInputs = ["Fahrenheit","Celsius","Kelvin"]
    let tempOutputs = ["Fahrenheit","Celsius","Kelvin"]
    
    
    switch (inputUnit, outputUnit) {
    case("Fahrenheit","Celsuis"):
        outputTemp = ((inputTemp - 32))
    default:
        outputTemp = inputTemp
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section{
                    Text("Input Temperature")
            
                    Picker("Select your input measurement", selection: $inputUnit) {
                        ForEach(tempInputs, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    TextField("Temperature", value: $inputTemp, format: .number)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Output Temperature")
                    
                    Picker("Select your Output measurement", selection: $outputUnit) {
                        ForEach(tempOutputs, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    
                    
                    
                    TextField("Output Temperature", value: $outputTemp, format: .number)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                
              
            }
            .navigationTitle("Temp Converter")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Done") {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the switch statement to work and help choose the correct logic to use for conversion.

Comment: Look into `Measurement` it already comes built in with `UnitTemperature` this is the very long approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Measurement<UnitTemperature>` comes built in with the code you need to convert temperatures.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TempConversionView: View {
    typealias U = UnitTemperature
    //Use measurements to keep the value and unit together
    
    @State private var input: Measurement<U> = .init(value: 0, unit: .celsius)
    //Use measurements to keep the value and unit together
    @State private var output: Measurement<U> = .init(value: 0, unit: .fahrenheit)
    //Use picker to convert `output`
    @State private var outputUnit: U = .baseUnit()
    
    let supported: [U] = [.fahrenheit, .celsius, .kelvin]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section{
                    Text("Input Temperature")
                    
                    MeasurementEditView(m: $input, supported: supported)
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Output Temperature")
                    
                    Text(output.value, format: .number)
                    UnitPicker(unit: $outputUnit, supported: supported)
                    //Convert when the input changes or when the unit changes
                    //**This** is where you would put the `switch` in your code
                        .task(id: "\(input) \(outputUnit.symbol.description)", {
                            let new = input.converted(to: outputUnit)
                            //This part is buggy needs to stay exactly like this, weird but keep it or the assert will fail.
                            self.output.value = new.value
                            self.output = new
                            //Ensure the changes were made
                            assert(output.unit == outputUnit, "Units are not matching check implementation")
                            assert(output.value == new.value, "Value is not matching check implementation")
                        })
                }
                //Move up so it is displayed
                .navigationTitle("Temp Converter")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
}
//Works for all measurements
struct MeasurementEditView<D>: View where D: Dimension{
    ///Measurement to change
    @Binding var m: Measurement<D>
    ///Options for units
    let supported: [D]
    
    init(m: Binding<Measurement<D>>, supported: [D]){
        self._m = m
        //Add the value of the unit for the measurement if not included int he supported units
        if !supported.contains(m.wrappedValue.unit){
            self.supported = supported + [m.wrappedValue.unit]
        }else{
            self.supported = supported
        }
    }
    var valueProxy: Binding<Double>{
        .init {
            m.value
        } set: { new in
            m = .init(value: new, unit: m.unit)
        }
    }
    var unitProxy: Binding<D>{
        .init {
            m.unit
        } set: { new in
            m = .init(value: m.value, unit: new)
        }
    }
    var body: some View{
        TextField("Value", value: valueProxy, format:.number)
        UnitPicker(unit: unitProxy, supported: supported)
    }
}
//Works with all dimensions
struct UnitPicker<D>: View where D: Dimension{
    ///Unit to change
    @Binding var unit: D
    ///Options for units
    let supported: [D]
    var body: some View{
        Picker("Unit", selection: $unit) {
            ForEach(supported, id: \.symbol) { unit in
                Text(unit.symbol).tag(unit)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is very cool to see. Some is over my head as just starting with SwiftUI but nice to see where logic can go; been struggling as to where to put things.